# Calculating monthly UST3M returns

Tags: portfolio-optimization, capm, variance

I am trying compute a variance/covariance matrix for 5 stocks using monthly returns. I plan to use CAPM (using monthly log returns) as the expected return and the US 3-month Treasury Bill (UST3M) monthly return as the risk free return in the variance/covariance formula, yielding the excess returns. How should I compute the monthly UST3M return from historical data?

Comment: For the monthly return take one twelvth of $\frac{TB3MS}{100-TB3MS}$ where TB3MS is given here https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/TB3MS. That should be close enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should I use the arithmetic mean of the calculated TB3MS returns (0.06%) in the CAPM formula for expected monthly returns of the stocks, or should I use the current TB3MS (4.29%)?